# Querying Eigen::Vector4cd implementation, specifically its norm() method

Tags: c++, complex-numbers, eigen3

I've been experimenting with what I understand to be the latest Eigen library release (3.4.0), specifically aiming to work with 4-vectors in complex number space. I note that `Eigen::Vector4cd` is defined by `typedef Matrix< std::complex< double >, 4, 1 > Eigen::Vector4cd` and, as far as I can tell, merely implements its `norm()` method according to this parameterization of the base template class, without further specialisation. As such—in any event, this is what I am finding from my experiments—this method, in this instance, is returning the norm as a *real*, rather than a *complex* scalar (double) in instances where I would expect the latter.

Maybe I'm missing something fundamental and my expectations are off, but I would have thought the `norm` of a complex vector would, itself, have a complex value? Is that not the case?

To be specific, I was expecting that the `norm()` method of the `Vector4cd` type would return the equivalent of the following bespoke function:

```
std::complex<double> complex_norm(const Eigen::Vector4cd& vec4) {
    return sqrt(
          pow(vec4(0), 2.)
        + pow(vec4(1), 2.)
        + pow(vec4(2), 2.)
        + pow(vec4(3), 2.)
    );
}
```

and when I call this function with a complex 4-vector constructed as follows:

```
Eigen::Vector4cd fourVecA;
fourVecA << std::complex<double>(1., 0.),
        std::complex<double>(2., 0.),
        std::complex<double>(2., 0.),
        std::complex<double>(0., 5.);
```

I get the result that I would expect: `(0., 4.)`.

If, however, I call:

```
fourVecA.norm();
```

I get `5.83095` as a non-complex double result, this being equivalent to `sqrt(34)` where `34` is the sum of all the squares taken *as if* I were working in the real, rather than the complex, number space.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are obtaining the correct value, but maybe I'm missing something here. The L2 norm of a complex number is a real number given by the following:

[image: Complex norm]

This shouldn't change when using a vector of complex numbers. The square root of the sum of all complex conjugate products should be still a positive real value.